# Reading and writing PKCS#11 objects

Tags: pkcs#11

I'm trying to convert some PCSC code to PKCS#11 calls in C. In PCSC, to access an EF, I have to first select it, then read or write it. I'm looking at the PKCS#11 documentation, but I don't see corresponding object management functions. The closest seem to be C_GetAttributeValue and C_SetAttributeValue, but I'm not sure how to use them, even after looking at some example code. For example, how do I select the data object to access? Also, how do I set the template? Some example C code would be helpful.

Thanks!

Edit: After some research it seems to be that SelectFile() roughly maps to C_FindObjectsInit() and C_FindObjects(), which returns a CK_OBJECT_HANDLE, and ReadFile() roughly maps to C_GetAttributeValue(). I'm trying to use this model, but my first call to C_FindObjectsInit() returns CKR_ARGUMENTS_BAD. Here's my source:

```
unsigned char *tokenLabel;
CK_ATTRIBUTE labelTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_LABEL, NULL_PTR, 0}
};
tokenLabel = (unsigned char *) malloc(labelLen);
// Sets the tokenLabel here
labelTemplate[0].pValue = tokenLabel;
labelTemplate[0].ulValueLen = labelLen;
ret = C_FindObjectsInit(hSession, labelTemplate, 1);
if(ret != CKR_OK)
{
    return -1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm simply trying to find an object that matches a particular label.

Comment: You should take a look at my [older answer to the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29109205/3325704).

Comment: Thanks. I did. I've browsed through your source, and also the PKCS11 docs, but I still don't quite get it. What exactly should I do to access an object in a PKCS11 token? From what I've gathered so far, I need to do a C_FindObjectsInit(), C_FindObjects(), then C_GetAttributeValue() to select and read an object. I'm trying to do that but having some trouble as I've described in the updated original post.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in your code but PKCS#11 implementation (library you are using) can require you to provide some specific attributes in search template (i.e. CKA_CLASS etc.). I think you should consult its documentation to see if there is such requirement and you should also try to enable logging (if your PKCS#11 library provides such feature) which may provide you more details about the error you are getting.